# Url to access azure webservice after deployment

Tags: java, web-services, azure-web-app-service

When I access my web service running on tomcat on my local mahine, I can accesss it,say,

```
http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/something/users
```

But after I have deployed it to Azure, I am not able to access it if I do,

```
http://example.azurewebsites.net/UserManagement/something/users
```

I get resource not found !! Am I making a mistake?

Edit: I created my web service on Eclipse as a dynamic web project and ran it on tomcat. Then I uploaded it successfully on Azure as a web app using Azure plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Been a while since I played with Azure, but there should be logs somewhere within the Azure portal.

Comment: @Rorschach, Could you post more details for helping solve the issue? Did you deploy the app on Azure WebApps or other services like API Apps? What steps of your deployment were?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT:I have editted my question.

Comment: @AndrewS: I enabled logs but it says that the access url(as above) was requested from a client machine(details on my machine) but nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rorschach, According to your web service url, I think you have refered to the article [Create a Hello World Web App for Azure in Eclipse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-eclipse-create-hello-world-web-app/) deployed your dynamic web project on Azure via publish as Azure Web App in Azure plugin for Eclipse.

To troubleshoot for the webapp, please check whether your project deployment named `UserManagement` had been deployed at the path `site\wwwroot\webapps` via Kudu console which can be access via url `https://example.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

If the directory `UserManagement` doesn't exist at the path `wwwroot\webapps`, I suggest that you can export the project as a war file and deploy it via drag into the `webapps` path using Kudu console or upload with ftp, then restart the webapp and try to access again.

If the directory `webapps` doesn't exist at the path `wwwroot`, I suggest that you can configure the Java web container at the `Application Settings` tab on Azure portal and re-deploy it.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.